# Adjust so that the condition panel appears only when a correct file is loaded

Tags: r, shiny

I inserted a condition panel so that as soon as the file is loaded by fileInput. It is working, however, I would like this panel to be shown only when the correct file is loaded. As it is, even with the wrong format files, the condition panel appears, as shown in the image. Can someone help me?? The executable code is below:

Thank you!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(ggplot2)
library(shinythemes)
library(rdist)
library(openxlsx) 
library(geosphere)
library(rgdal)

function.cl<-function(df,k){
  
}

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
             "Cl", 
             tabPanel("Solution",
                      fileInput("data", h3("Excel or Shapefile import"),
                                accept = c(".xlsx",".shp",".shx",".dbf"),
                                multiple= T),  
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          
                          sliderInput("Slider", h5(""),
                                      min = 2, max = 4, value = 3),
                          
                          conditionalPanel(
                            "output.fileUploaded == true",
                            tags$p(h3("Are you satisfied?")),
                            tags$b(h5("(a) Choose others filters")),
                            tags$b(h5("(b) Choose number of clusters"))), 
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          tabsetPanel(      
                            tabPanel("Solution", plotOutput("ScatterPlot"))))
                        
                      ))))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  v <- reactiveValues(df = NULL,clear=FALSE)
  
  observeEvent(input$data, {
    if(any(grepl(".xlsx",input$data$name))){
      v$df <- read.xlsx(input$data$datapath) 
    }else if(any(grepl(".shp",input$data$name))){
      shpDF <- input$data
      failed <- F
      if(!any(grepl(".shx",input$data$name))){
        failed<-T
      }
      
      if(!any(grepl(".dbf",input$data$name))){
        failed<-T
      }
      
      if(failed){
        
        sendSweetAlert(
          session = session,
          title = "Error !!",
          text = "You Need 3 files, '*.shp', '*shx' and '*.dbf'",
          type = "error"
        )
        
      }else{
        prevWD <- getwd()
        uploadDirectory <- dirname(shpDF$datapath[1])
        setwd(uploadDirectory)
        for (i in 1:nrow(shpDF)){
          file.rename(shpDF$datapath[i], shpDF$name[i])
        }
        shpName <- shpDF$name[grep(x=shpDF$name, pattern="*.shp")]
        shpName<-substr(shpName,1,nchar(shpName)-4)
        
        setwd(prevWD)
        shpFile<-readOGR(dsn=uploadDirectory,layer=shpName)
        
        v$df<-shpFile@data
      } 
    }else{
      sendSweetAlert(
        session = session,
        title = "Error !!",
        text = "Wrong File",
        type = "error"
      )
      
    }
    v$clear <- TRUE 
  })
  
  
  Modelcl<-reactive({if (!is.null(v$df)) {
    function.cl(v$df,input$Slider)
  }
  })
  
  
  output$fileUploaded <- reactive({
    v$clear
  })
  outputOptions(output, 'fileUploaded', suspendWhenHidden=FALSE)
  
  
  output$ScatterPlot <- renderPlot({
    Modelcl()[[1]]
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, forget my answer. In your first code, add `return(NULL)` after the `sendSweetAlert`. In this way, this will interrupt the code inside the observer, and `vfile$clear <- TRUE` will not be executed if a sweet alert is sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `return(NULL)` after the `sendSweetAlert`s:

```
sendSweetAlert(
  session = session,
  title = "Error !!",
  text = "You Need 3 files, '*.shp', '*shx' and '*.dbf'",
  type = "error"
)
return(NULL)
```

and

```
  sendSweetAlert(
    session = session,
    title = "Error !!",
    text = "Wrong File",
    type = "error"
  )
  return(NULL)
```

The `return(NULL)` statement interrupts the code in the observer. In this way the statement `v$clear <- TRUE` will not be executed when a sweet alert is sent.